# Use Android device as a barcode reader for PC

Tags: applications, barcode

Is there an app that allows your Android device to act as a barcode reader, in such a way that it can send something like keyboard inputs to a computer in real-time?

Answer (score 10):

I made a free alternative: [Barcode to PC: Wi-Fi scanner](https://barcodetopc.com/).

It sends realtime keystrokes, **no copy&paste** required, works everywhere

Comment: I tried your app, but for my sorry, phone and server couldnt connect :/
I tried and manual adding server.... the same Android 5.1 / Win 7 64bit

Comment: Best one i´ve found after trying about 20 different apps.

Comment: @minimiro Did you add the server to windows firewall exceptions? If yes it may be your antivirus that blocks the app.

Comment: Free and works very well without any configuration necessary. Thanks

Comment: @filippo Thank you so much! The app is so well done and works seamlessly. I can't believe it's free! Thank you. You deserve more upvotes.

Comment: works, but is actually shareware (even though it's marked GPL). it will ask you to upgrade to the paid version and some features are locked, a bit annoying. i [asked the folks from binary eye](https://github.com/markusfisch/BinaryEye/issues/48) to implement a similar "ping URL" feature which could be promising...

Answer (score 4):

[Bluetooth Barcode Scanner](https://market.android.com/details?id=net.usefulapps.bluetoothscanner)

[WiFi Barcode Scanner](http://market.android.com/details?id=at.idsoftware.barcode)

Comment: Both are paid apps.

Comment: See filippo's answer below for a good free alternative.

Answer (score 1):

1. Install [Barcode Scanner](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.zxing.client.android). In Barcode Scanner app settings check "copy to clipboard" after scanning.
2. Install [ClipSync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=be.bdwm.clipsync)

Now your PC should have the info in clipboard so do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>.

I haven't tested it myself but it should work, and both apps are free.

Comment: Instead of ClipSync I use [UniClip! Clipboard Sync](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.piyushagade.uniclip&hl=en). It has support for Win, Mac and Linux.

Answer (score 0):

I made a (free) app that shows scanned codes on webpage, allowing easy copy, updated real-time.

[Web Barcode](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.zielm.wbc)